# Connections to tomcat server are not read by the server

Tags: java, tomcat, debian, tomcat8

Running tomcat8 in a debian server some connections are not processed. They are established but tomcat does not get data from the socket.  Looking at the connection I can see:

```
root@idpopen:/var/log# ss -4 -t -w -p|grep 208.201
tcp    CLOSE-WAIT 808    0      xx.xx.xx.112:https xx.xx.208.201:57263    users:(("java",pid=4351,fd=81))
tcp    ESTAB      735    0      xx.xx.xx.112:https xx.xx.208.201:59829    users:(("java",pid=4351,fd=97))
```

Data stay in the buffer and are not read by the application (java).

If I close the browser the connection goes in CLOSE-WAIT state.

After multiple reload on the browser I get a correct connection and tomcat work properly for the following connection. However, if the browser is closed and open again I get the same behaviour.

Not all applications in the same tomcat instance show the same problem.

Is it possible to debugging the connection? Tomcat does not provide any log because it is not processing the incoming request.

Comment: I have installed httpd to proxy tomcat using ajp connector and it works properly. The problem could be in the connector but for now it is solved.